# resource comparison between socket.io vs rest api

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am building application on socket.io and node.js expressjs 4 .
for my opinion socket.io takes much resources then Rest APIs.
I want to know how i can compare RestApis vs Socket.io in terms of memory ,CPU usage .and which is best for large applications
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare memory and CPU usage i suggest executing a big number of queries of each one separately (like a thousand) and watching the memory and cpu of the process. Now which is better it's not that simple. It all depends... Socket.io is designed to be a real-time tool, so in large applications where there are a lot of real-time operations, it's better. But in large applications where real-time is really not an issue i believe(never really tested to know the numbers) you can get lesser memory usage using RESTful APIs, mainly because websocket is stateful, so the server needs to have every connection in it's memory. Another thing to put in mind is that HTTP protocol has a lot of goodies that websocket doesn't like gzipping, cache, routing, SEO, proxy, and much more.

A good article about that: [REST vs WebSocket](http://blog.arungupta.me/rest-vs-websocket-comparison-benchmarks/)

Answer (score 0):

You might get help from mention below blogs

http://www.pubnub.com/blog/websockets-vs-rest-api-understanding-the-difference/

http://blog.arungupta.me/rest-vs-websocket-comparison-benchmarks/

These contion the complete detail of the difference.

Comment: thanks for your participation,I need comparison in memory and CPU usage ,which use most of our resource socket or http?